# Version Number in sqflite

Tags: sql, flutter, sqflite

What is the use of version number in SQL package used while opening the data base

```
Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
  await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE Test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, value INTEGER, num REAL)');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's used when you upgrade your database, for example you need to add new table, or columns to existing one, then you increment version and override `onUpgrade` method and execute sql scripts in it.

Comment: Does changing version overrides current data base